# Sabre Scribe or Script Assistance

Tags: sabre

Is it possible to create math functions in Sabre Scripts?

For example, if the fare is 250.00 then multiply it by 10% and fill in the value?

I have read thru all sabre documentation, and don't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

The basic sabre scribe developer guide explains this in the Expressions section (page 10 on my document):

[image: Sabre Scribe Expressions]

Comment: can you have a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74642466/login-failed-on-sabre-ota-hotelavailrq ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFINE [fare=DECIMAL:7:OPT:::]
DEFINE [newFareDiv=DECIMAL:7:OPT:::]
DEFINE [newFareCombined=DECIMAL:7:OPT:::]
DEFINE [newFare=DECIMAL:7:OPT:::]


[fare] = "250.00"
DEFAULT [fare] = [fare]

[newFareDiv] = [fare] / 100
DEFAULT [newFareDiv] = [newFareDiv]

[newFare] = [newFareDiv] * 25
DEFAULT [newFare] = [newFare]

[newFareCombined] = [fare] + [newFare]
DEFAULT [newFareCombined] = [newFareCombined]

WINDOW
1. Divide (/) Fare by 100 = [newFareDiv]

2. Times (*) value by 25 = [newFare]

3. Add (+) value to orig. Fare = [newFareCombined]


Orig. Fare = [fare]


New Fare = [newFareCombined]
ENDWINDOW
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).